# Is it possible to ban a trolling user?

Tags: discussion

Is it possible to ban from Stack Overflow a trolling user like "[Smarter than Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4316908/smarter-than-jon-skeet)", who is asking questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27255962/if-free-standing-functions-are-bad-and-objects-are-good-then-how-do-i-write-the)?

Quoting the (now deleted) question:

> ### If free-standing functions are bad and objects are good, then how do I write the “Hello, World!” program?
>
> ---
>
> If I'm following the philosophy of seeing everything as an object,
>   then should I make a class like
>
> ```
> class HelloWorlder
> {
> private: 
>     const static char text [] = "Hello, world!";
> public: 
>     HelloWorlder();
>     ~HelloWorlder();
>     void print_text() {std::cout << text << std::endl;}
> }
> ```
>
> to use in my "Hello, World!" program???

Comment: Looks like a sock puppet a bit. How does that OP know about Jon Skeet being a member for just today?

Comment: Surprised how Stack overflow could allow such a name. :P

Comment: I'm tempted to give him the benefit of the doubt here. He certainly *could* be trolling, but unless he's posted that question 4 times in a row, its hard to say he's not just bitter and confused. Of course, if he did that, the auto-post ban would quickly hit, and the problem fixes itself.

Comment: Assume the user name were not visible, and then the question appears mundane. Whether the name is a troll attempt or not does not impact the content of the question.

Comment: In other words, judge the question, not the user.

Comment: @Compass Sometimes, it's better to solve the problem at the source (getting rid of the user) than to constantly treat the symptoms (the terrible questions).

Comment: @Mysticial The whole point here is that the question isn't terrible.  If a bad user contributes good content, don't throw out the baby with the bathwater.

Comment: @Servy I don't know about you, but that linked (deleted) question is a pretty terrible question (and quite an obvious troll attempt even without looking at the name).

Comment: @Mysticial Yet the trolling attempts will be quickly identified and the user quickly punished if they continue to do so. Jumping the gun doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Mysticial I was missing an "if" in my last comment.  *If* the question isn't terrible, it doesn't need to get thrown out with the user.  If it is terrible, sure.

Comment: I don't think it's terrible, but it's basically a reenactment of the old "verb vs. noun" holy war in OOP, so it's borderline flamebait and not very useful IMHO.

Comment: I think it's hilarious, but should live on programming forums not Stack Overflow.

Comment: @MorphingDragon I'd point out that that is part of the reason forums suck for trying to find information.  They don't *need* to suck as badly as they do, but because people do troll them it becomes harder to use them for everyone else.  So no, it doesn't belong here, there, or anywhere.

Comment: @MichaelT I actually find some of the programming forums to be better than stack overflow and many of them have their own residential trolls.

It's up to the moderators of each site to decide what kind of trolls they want.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you suspect a user of trolling, flag one of their posts and describe what led you to that conclusion.

In this case, given that they've previously created accounts named "John Skeet is Overrated", as well as a few other choice names (on accounts that were trolling before I removed them), I'm leaning towards troll. Account removed.

Comment: What did Jon Skeet do to deserve such hostility??

Comment: @Keith - I could list around 732,089 reasons

Comment: @Keith - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts

Comment: @Keith nothing, he's probably trolling himself

Comment: However that is a limited scope of trolling, a very obvious troll. How do we identify trolls more effectively?